# Build expression dynamically to call Expression.GreaterThan()

Tags: c#, expression

I'm trying to choose the method in `Expression` dynamically at runtime. For example, I want achieve something similar to what I'm trying below:

```
ConstantExpression one = Expression.Constant(1);
ConstantExpression two = Expression.Constant(2);
// Here the 'GreaterThan' is the method name received at runtime:
var method = typeof(Expression).GetMethods().Single(mi => mi.Name == "GreaterThan" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);
var expr = Expression.Call(method, one, two);
```

At the last line, I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' of method 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression GreaterThan(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)''
```

What I want to do is to build the lambda function by choosing methods in `Expression` dynamically at run time. Here, the method name will refer to some method that compares to numbers (or strings) depending on the expression method.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is dynamic? The operation values (i.e. the type of "one" and "two")? Or the type of the operation ("GreaterThan", "LessThen")?

If it's the former, you don't need to do anything as the expression builder will take care of it.

In

```
Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(2));
```

and

```
Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Constant("Some"), Expression.Constant("text"));
```

the proper greater than operators for ints and strings will be automatically chosen.

If it's the latter you want, i.e. dynamically choosing the operation, you need to write

```
var expr = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { one, two });
```

Which means you need to invoke the expression method to get the GreaterThan expression thus yielding the same result as if you had written `Expression.GreaterThan(one, two)`.

Calling `Expression.Call` on an expression method is akin to creating an expression to create expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid using reflection here and use **switch** instead to build it. Using this approach allow to get all the benefits of strong typing. See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically as an example.